# Has Android silently updated their definition of "small, normal, large, xlarge" screen sizes?

Tags: android, screen-size

Android has a [Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#OpenGL) that shows the device screen size distribution.

According to the data today, there are 89.8% devices that are classified as "normal".

However, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15096763/7870874), which can be verified by this [official document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ScreenSizeQualifier), devices with a diagonal length larger than 5 inches is already classified as large.

Where, as we all know, a very large percentage of Android devices nowadays have screen sizes larger than 5 inches. **This contradicts with the data shown in the Dashboard.**

I believe Android uses [this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#screenLayout) to collect data about screen size.
That means, probably a device with screen larger than 5 inches is returning itself as "normal" to Google.

Why is this happening? Has Google updated their definition of screen sizes without updating [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ScreenSizeQualifier)?
(In fact, I suspect pixel density is also taken into account of classifying the size of a device. But I cannot find any related definition)

Comment: I suspect density pixel (dp) is the criteria used for this classification rather than physical screen size.

Comment: @Talha Isn't dp (density-independent pixel) can be converted to physical size? (That's how I understand dp)

Answer (score 0):

The answer can actually be very simple...

#### Classification is not done by measuring diagonal length

If you look carefully, 480dp * 640dp, which is the minimum size of a large device, is a 4:3 aspect ratio.
Did you see a phone with 4:3 aspect ratio nowadays? No / Rare.
So, it is highly possible that a large device has to be longer than **both** 480dp in width, and 640dp in height, to be classified as large.
And *for a 16:9 device with 480dp width of 2.0 density, it means 6.11 inches diagonal length, which is indeed not common*.